# How to mock ftp.nlst() in unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, ftp, mocking, stub

I'm trying to get my unit tests working, especially this `ftp.nlst`

```
def get_file_list(ftp_conn):

    filematch = '*.csv'

    ftp_list = ftp_conn.nlst(filematch)

    return ftp_list
```

Can someone help with the unittest below? Thanks.

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP()
        self.ftp.nlst = MagicMock(return_value=[])

    
    def test_example(self):
?????
```

Comment: Hi I just have some updates on this question, I haven't finished my editing...

Comment: I've updated the minimal example in the question, should be easier for people to reproduce the problem, hopefully...

Comment: What do you mean which one should you use? Is there any error?

Answer (score 1):

You have mocked the `ftp.nlst()` method and its returned value, you only need to pass in the `self.ftp` object to the `get_file_list()` function. Finally, assert whether the return value meets expectations.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
def get_file_list(ftp_conn):

    filematch = '*.csv'

    ftp_list = ftp_conn.nlst(filematch)

    return ftp_list
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
import ftplib
from main import get_file_list


class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP()
        self.ftp.nlst = MagicMock(return_value=[1, 2, 3])

    def test_get_file_list(self):
        actual = get_file_list(self.ftp)
        self.assertEqual(actual, [1, 2, 3])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66458222/test_main.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66458222/main.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/66458222/test_main.py      13      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        17      0   100%
```